# Javascript remove and add class with a slow transition on a carousel

Tags: javascript, html, animate.css

I have created a carousel with Javascript. I am using `animate.css` which can enable me to use some cool transitions. I have a class called `fadeInLeft` also applied to each `div`. I am now trying to remove `fadeInLeft` and add `FadeOutLeft` to make the transition smooth. However, at the moment everything I have tried just makes the current slide disappear sharply. The idea after the current slide has faded out to the left I would like the next slide to fade in from the left. Can anyone please advice me how I could achieve this?

```
var index = 1;

    function plusIndex(n) {
        index = index + 1;
        showImage(index);
    }

    showImage(1);

    function showImage(n){
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel");
        if(n > x.length){index = 1};
        if(n< 1){ index = x.length};
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        x[index-1].style.display = "block";
    }

<i type="button" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" class="fa fa-chevron-left arrowLeft arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i type="button" onclick="plusIndex(1)" class="fa fa-chevron-right arrowRight arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div class="carousel carousel1 animated fadeInLeft"></div>
    <div class="carousel carousel2 animated fadeInLeft"></div>
    <div class="carousel carousel3 animated fadeInLeft"></div>
```

Comment: use css transitions and do not set display per js but by css. instead set/remove css classes by js

Comment: @beertwenty Can you please provide me a working code example of your coz right not I can't test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Comment: I added this with Jquery but it just adds fade out to the new slide and not the active one.: 

$('.arrow').click(function() {
    $(".carousel").removeClass('fadeInLeft');
    $(".carousel").addClass('fadeOutLeft');
});

Answer (score 1):

1. your tags have many classes
   firstly you select the tag maybe like this:

   ```
   var div = document.getElementsByClassName[0];
   ```
2. you get the class list and remove `fadeInLeft`

   ```
   div.classList.remove("fadeInLeft");
   ```
3. you add another class

   ```
   div.classList.add("fadeOutLeft")
   ```

Comment: added this with Jquery but it just adds fade out to the new slide and not the active one.: $('.arrow').click(function() { $(".carousel").removeClass('fadeInLeft'); $(".carousel").addClass('fadeOutLeft'); });

Comment: @beertwenty You need to specify which carousel shout fade in. (ID, .active)

Comment: @PaulStrobach Using Jquery, How would I select which oen is active

Comment: Use `:nth-child` https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ and select the (index-1)-th child

Comment: in the css? but the slider works fine with js at the moment.

Comment: @beertwenty no use `$(".carousel:nth-child("+String(index-1)+")")`

Comment: $('.arrow').click(function() {
    $(".carousel").removeClass('fadeInLeft');
    $(".carousel").addClass('fadeOutLeft');
    $(".carousel:nth-child("+String(index-1)+")");
});

Comment: @beertwenty No this is just for selecting the element that shall be animated/shown. (And I just see: Do not take index-1 but only index)